# Putting hyphen on keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

My problem is simple, i need to put a hyphen where is usually @ or . or .com on keyboard, everything else should stay the same.
I know it's to do with setKeyListener of my TextView or perchance there is an already done input type for this?

Precisely what i mean is to get a hyphen (-) character where www. character is.
[image]

Comment: Are you writing the soft keyboard? Or are you trying to control the behavior of dozens, if not hundreds, of existing soft keyboard implementations?

Comment: im not even sure what u mean with this :)
probably second tho :P

Comment: updated my main post to make it more clear.